# godaddy header issues

Tags: php

on godaddy's servers if any information exists before a redirect is done ill get that header error on the page. but on my local pc that doesnt happend. how can i set up wamp to act the same as godaddys servers do? to show me all header errors

i should have errors turned on but what else do i need to turn on. so i can save me some time and save my breath from cursing godaddy out lol.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because, on your PC, [`output_buffering`](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) is activated, and not on your final webserver.

Setting that entry to `Off` in your php.ini should bring you closer to what you have on godaddy's machine.

About errors, you can have a look at

- [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) : on your development machine, it should be set to `E_ALL` in php.ini, so you can see all kinds of error. this can also be set with the function [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
- [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) should also be set to `On` in php.ini, so you immediatly notice errors. This can also be set with [`ini_set`](http://php.net/ini_set) ; and it should be set to `Off` on your production server, so that users don't see errors on the website *(what could they understand about those, except find them annoying ? )*